# Table inside div not displayed in Opera

Tags: html, css, html-table, opera

I have 'inherited' a website and I am among other things to maintain it. However, recently I noticed that while the site behaves reasonably in most of the major browsers (FF; IE 7,8,9; Chrome), in Opera it is rendered completely wrong.

After some investigation, I found the issue is that `<table>`s in Opera are not shown, in particular, their computed style contains this: `display: none;`. This struck me as odd, as I have explicitly included in the style for this element `display: table;` which is also the default, and in the stylesheets linked, I can't see anywhere `display: none;` that could cause the table to not be displayed.

All other mentioned browsers had `display: table;` in the computed style for the `<table>` elements, even without it being explicit in the stylesheet.

An example of this is provided below.
Tested under Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 64 bit. It has been confirmed that under Windows the effect is the same (FF, Chrome and IE show tables; Opera doesn't).

Tested with and without an HTTP server (`http://localhost/test1.html` and `file:///var/www/test1.html`) and there is no difference in either browsers.

I am in little doubt that the problem is on my side, but I'm out of ideas and any help would be appreciated. Apologies if this is a trivial question or a misunderstanding of HTML or CSS on my side (or the original developer), I am mostly a PHP programmer.

The shortest possible example of the behavior I experienced is this:

`test1.html`

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="menuItem">
   <table class="menuItem"><tr bgcolor="black"><td>ASD</td></tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

`test.css`

```
.menuItem {
    content:"";
    border: 2px green;
    width: inherit;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}
table.menuItem {
    content:"";
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: whats with the `content:"";` decleration? thats a css attribute that should only be used in conjuction with `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors. try removing those and see what happens.

Comment: I think it's an Opera bug, report it on Opera site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried it myself and if you remove the `content: ""` from both style declarations, everything works.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes it indeed. That property was (I think) supposed to be part of a clearing stylesheet, how it got there is a mystery.

Answer (score -1):

It appears Opera has decided not to follow the specification for [CSS Level 2 which states that content only applies to `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content)

Removing the `content:"";` from both style declerations fixes this in Opera.

P.S. IE7 obeying a standard while opera dosn't, crazy times we live in

Comment: This is because Opera is more advanced than that and [it supports CSS3, which states it applies to *all* elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#content).